# Create PDF file taking huge data from MySQL using PHP

Tags: php, pdf, concatenation

I want to make a PDF file which will contain huge data such as 12 months data.
Each month contain 500 rows from MySQL table. I have tried with FPDF but it takes too much time that is unacceptable. If there is any other better PHP library or class to make it easily and not make the system busy?

If there is any script which will take 12 months data one month by one month and write it to PDF one by one and finally create the PDF file?

Comment: you want smething like html to pdf?

Comment: Will the old data (i.e. in previous months) change at all? If not, then you could keep a file copy of `previous-months.pdf` and just regenerate the current month. Then when serving to the user, merge the two PDF files - that will probably be quicker.

Comment: Alternatively, when a user wishes to download a long PDF report, queue the requirement in a table and use a cron-job generation plus email to send it to them.

Comment: I have tried HTML to PDF but it also take long time. I have 40000 users. So I need huge disk space to store previous months PDF. It is not possible for me.

Answer (score 2):

I routinely create very large PDFs from PHP using (usually) the same method.  First I create a web page version of the document and output that to a file.  Then I run the file through wkhtmltopdf.  I've had consistently more success with this method than any other.  The HTML should be quick to generate and  wkhtmltopdf is surprisingly fast and efficient.  Plus you can use CSS3 techniques for elaborate formatting.

For extremely large PDFs I've also generated smaller ones and then merged them with pdfmeld.  This also gives you the option of adding bookmarks.

Comment: Thanks for your valuable suggestion. Please give a demo link if possible?

Answer (score 1):

Building a PDF is always very long. If you have a huge amount of ressource, it will be very very long, you can't avoid that. 
I can see one way of doing it a way that is softer for your users :

Sending them a html render, and then with Ajax make the pdf generation asynchronous. So you can display a status bar. and inform your users your are performing their demand.

Then the generation can be technicaly performed by three ways :

- using fpdf and hard coding the disposition
- using dom2pdf or such a library to make your html render a pdf file
- create a latex string and then using `proc_open` to ask the latex compilator to build a pdf file. It is a really fast and reliable tool but it needs you to have a dedicated server and not a shared host.

Answer (score 1):

```
 // you can used fpdf like this.
<?php
require('fpdf.php');

class PDF extends FPDF
{
   // Page header
  function Header()
  {
   // Logo
    $this->Image('logo.png',10,6,30);
     // Arial bold 15
     $this->SetFont('Arial','B',15);
    // Move to the right
    $this->Cell(80);
    // Title
   $this->Cell(30,10,'Title',1,0,'C');
   // Line break
   $this->Ln(20);
   }

  // Page footer
 function Footer()
 {
    // Position at 1.5 cm from bottom
   $this->SetY(-15);
   // Arial italic 8
   $this->SetFont('Arial','I',8);
   // Page number
   $this->Cell(0,10,'Page '.$this->PageNo().'/{nb}',0,0,'C');
}
}

// Instanciation of inherited class
$pdf = new PDF();
 $pdf->AliasNbPages();
 $pdf->AddPage();
 $pdf->SetFont('Times','',12);
for($i=1;$i<=40;$i++)
$pdf->Cell(0,10,'Printing line number '.$i,0,1);
$pdf->Output();
?>
```